Is it ethical to punish the buyers of sex but not the vendors?
In Sweden, it is illegal to buy sexual services, but there are not punitive measures against those who sell sexual services. This is to curb the incidence of prostitution in society without punishing people who turn to prostitution out of desperation or financial hardship.
I wonder if this is an example of a ‘pragmatic’ law, where the law is tailored towards the social ramifications it will have, in the particular society it is implemented in. For example, if you think prostitution should be illegal, but you don’t want to punish people who turn to prostitution, seeing them perhaps as victims of social circumstances and social structures, then you might find the law supportive of that goal.
However, I think laws can also be designed to reflect what is inherently right or wrong, even if the law has suboptimal secondary effects in society. From this perspective, what underlying analysis of “transactional” sexual services or sex acts, is being implied by this law? Why would it be inherently wrong to buy sex but not sell it?
For example, could you argue that it is wrong to buy sex because there is something about another person’s sexual capacity that is “off-limits” as a kind of exchangeable property, similar to how you cannot own slaves, or presumably, pay people to do certain extreme infringements on themselves, like mutilate themselves? Whereas it is legal to offer to sell such things because in that case, you are intentionally consenting to commodify some aspect of yourself from that “untouchable private sphere”? But then, would that undermine the unethicality of buying it, since apparently, your consent is what allows certain “protected property” to become a commodity of exchange? (Is there a parallel there between consensual murder and suicide: you cannot kill someone else even if someone asks you to, but if someone kills themself, there is an inherent reason why that isn’t in the same category of criminality?)

In order to clarify you question: Could you please give a reference to the Swedish law which considers "to buy sexual services" as illegal - if possible in English. Thanks.

Your question starts from the presumption that objective morality has to follow the  structure of abstract logic or legalism.
Abstract logic tends to lead to lots of cases that most humans consider very immoral.  Legalism, which tries to account for conflicting values, also, because of its inability to account for all circumstances, regularly ends up with multiple cases that most humans consider immoral.
The objective moralities that have been proposed and are much more widely accepted among philosophers today include a) utilitarian consequentialism, b) rights ethics, and c) virtue ethics.  Additionally, adding to consequentialism, prioritizing something other than individuals is another interesting alternative.  These would include both human society-based eusocial ethics, and life-based deep ecology.
Rights-based thinking is the closest to legalism of these more attractive current views.  You should note that your focus on rights-based thinking as an alternative to abstract logic, and the incorporation of rights thinking into a legal system, is just one of several approaches to objective morality.
You appear to recognize that rights-based ethics would allow commercial sex if the selling is voluntary.  And suggested some ways that a less than purely symmetric approach to commercialization could lead to it being moral to prosecute  only one party to a transaction, even if it were voluntary.  The idea of uneven power in a transaction, or uneven knowledge/rationality, and in particular the abuse/misuse of physical power or misleading information leading to immorality in a transaction on only one side, HAVE been developed in legal theory as amendments to free participation principles under rights-based thinking.
Rights-based thinking is not the only way to morally justify laws.  they can also be justified based on societal consequences, and given societal complexity, asymmetric legal treatment of the buyer and seller in a transaction can often be justifiable under consequentialism.  And logical consistency is not a big concern for consequentialism.
So under all of the currently preferred ways to do moral thinking in contemporary philosophy, I believe your answer would be "yes".

Objective ethics is an oxymoron. Political conflict arises in both small and large groups because individuals do not always agree on what is good; or if they agree on what is good then individuals do not always agree on the means to cause the good. There is no objective standard to establish what is good, or how one should act to cause the good, unless a group of individuals reaches subjective agreement on the matter in the dramatic context. Humans tend to regard murder, the killing of another with intention, as not good; but murderers act as if it is good to murder and may show no remorse.

@SystemTheory -- moral realism is what leads to objective morality.  That we do not always all agree on what objective morality consists of does not refute that there IS an objective morality.  Just as our disagreeing on what may exist physically or the appropriate way to solve a statistics problem, do not bring physical realism or math realism into question.

The assertion that moral realism proves or establishes or leads to objective morality is a tautology. There is only an abstract concept, objective morality, arising in the mind(s) of one or more subjects. What exists apart from the minds of subjects is a mystery.

Possible Rationale - Punishing Lust
In law there are rules, exceptions to the rules, and the rationale or reasons offered for establishing the rules and the exceptions. One reason to punish the buyers of sex (that I would reject as invalid) is to punish the vice of lust:
https://web.uncg.edu/dcl/courses/vicecrime/m1/part1.asp

A vice is a bad or undesirable character trait. The opposite of a vice is a virtue, which is a good or desirable character trait. For example, honesty is a virtue and dishonesty is a vice. There are many vices. Some of the most commonly referred to vices include greed, anger, lust, envy, gluttony, pride, and sloth (laziness). Each of these is a character trait we find in people which is, on the whole, undesirable. By comparison we can list some virtues including loyalty, bravery, honesty, compassion, humility, generosity and temperance. The language of virtue and vice goes back at least to the ancient Greeks who, as we will see later, spent a great deal writing about them. Much of this language is also employed in a religious context where it is said that there are “seven deadly sins” or vices and “seven heavenly virtues.” Wherever our familiarity with virtues and vices comes from what is in general agreement is that vices are character traits that we want to avoid and virtues are character traits that we should want to promote or cultivate.


It may be that the customer (John) of a prostitute is motivated by the vice of lust, but what about the actions of the prostitute? Certainly prostitutes themselves are not motivated by lust for their customers. If prostitutes are not motivated by lust, then what, if any, vice motivates them? We might find some prostitutes are motivated by greed (getting rich), but what about the significant amount of prostitutes who are in it to make a living? Are prostitutes motivated by vice?

Ape Psychology and Public Policy
When I studied law around thirty years ago it rapidly transformed into my effort to contemplate human social psychology underlying the rationale and rules of law. Why does the law of contracts use police coercion to enforce bargains between two or more people of majority age? Why are some bargains not enforceable, such as contracts for sex, or contracts with minors, as against public policy? The reasons are embedded in the bodies and minds of intelligent apes. Embedded in the emotional drama of human social psychology.
Philosophers tend to avoid understanding their own infantile or early life drama. When we ignore adaptive social psychology we fail to get to the root of attitudes and behavior patterns expressed in society. I have read that most conflicts in marriage are over money, sex, and how to raise the children. Should public courts be used to resolve contract disputes between prostitutes and their customers? Should public coercion, police force, be used to punish transactions of sex and money based on mutual consent?
Prostitution and gambling were prohibited by custom at various times in civilized societies I think using the rationale of adverse individual and social outcomes for women and communities. These prohibitions at times became institutionalized in religious doctrine. Historically men who gamble and visit prostitutes divert money away from the social agenda of supporting children in marriage. Prostitutes enrich themselves but produce no children or might tend to have children outside marriage.
Men and women with gambling or prostitution addictions will tend to discount and destroy natural resources more rapidly. In ancient times intelligent people seemed to have religious reverence for the land as a God-given natural ecosystem. Modern humans are generating money through fractional reserve banking, multiplying debt, ignoring the sin of Usury, discounting nature at the interest rate, and imploding natural ecosystems all over the world because we have no collective reverence for the works of God and/or Nature. These are problems of human desire and social drama that have no perfectly logical solutions under theories of law and public policy.
Edit: Anectdote
I knew a man in peer counseling who said during early life his dictatorial money-making father was an executive in a large chemical corporation and his mother would often punish him by striking him with her monogrammed hairbrush. This man had said he developed a ritual wherein he would sit in a car for long periods of time watching prostitutes walk in the street so he could lust for one of them before he approached her for sex. One night he approached an exceptionally beautiful prostitute. She was an undercover police officer. Two male officers arrested him for soliciting prostitution. To me such official deception is a sadistic reenactment on the part of the officers and court system rather than a mode of enforcing justice.

@ScottRowe - I made an edit that you might find of interest. I found the article on Vice, Law, and Crime to be interesting in part because some moralistic atheists think that secular society is somehow superior to religious doctrine. I do not object to atheism. But they seem to regard religion as a vice or sin in much the same way that a religious moralist seeks to eradicate the vice or sin found in others. I do not object to atheism because it is all part of pluralistic subjective experience. People want God or Objective Truth to exist as Ultimate Authority to validate their subjective views.

I suppose we could assume that wanting to stop people from doing (or even thinking) things that are incorrect, wasteful and harmful to themselves and others arises from a desire to help them. So then it just comes down to the source of the info that a thought or behavior is harmful: by seeing the results, or by having a moral theory. If wanting validation for subjective views is itself a vice, then the plot we are trying to till is awfully stony! How to even get started in such circumstances?

@ScottRowe WWJD? What would Jesus do? That is not the primary question I ask when I observe the speech and other actions of humans. The question is, if I were to speak and act as the other does in that dramatic context, then what would I be saying and doing? What would I want or desire? How would I be trying to get what I want? Would I be wicked (self-deceived) or just? In this way I count myself among the wicked and the just and I automatically judge some subjective views as valid and other subjective views as abhorrent and unworthy of validation. I want some of my judgments to be objective!

@ScottRowe You may be aware of person-centered therapy as described in this article https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK589708/ - The role of the counselor is to provide a nonjudgmental environment conducive to honest self-exploration. The idea of non-judgment is to accept the other person's subjective experience. This might be experienced as validation. I try to suspend judgment. But like Jesus I hold adverse judgments (Example: You justify your actions in the sight of man! But God reads your hearts! What man thinks important, God holds in contempt!). How do we improve subjective views?

Keep looking at what results from them? I had a psychology professor who said that your beliefs are projected out to the world through your 'attitude', and they bounce off the world and hit you. Sometimes it takes a while for the bounce back to happen. He said all your 'results' come back to you after 7 years. He also said that your values are shown by 2 things: how you spend your time, and how you spend your money. That's about it, I think.

I accept that my cat subjectively wants to claw the sofa. I in turn subjectively don't want him to, so I objectively spray him with water, while trying to not get objectively angry. We're allowed to tell people "No".

@ScottRowe Values are subjective. In therapy the therapist values their social status and role as a "healer". The patient or suffering person spends time and money to be with the therapist. The therapist passively allows or actively demands that the suffering person reveal their inner world. Parents and authority figures almost never reveal their inner world to children. The suffering person thus gives money, time, and psychological transparency to the "healer". Maybe the therapist gives healing value to the patient. Maybe the therapist is a sadist or passive pussy collecting the Temple tax.

Framing issue
Your question assumes that laws are rational and meaningful.
Please reflect on Lao Tzu:

The more prohibitions you have, the less virtuous people will be


The more laws and restrictions there are, the poorer people become. The more sharp weapons there are, the more troubled the state. The more cunning and cleverness, the more frequently do things fall into disorder


Governing a large country is like frying a small fish. You spoil it with too much poking
The more laws and commands there are, the more thieves and robbers there will be

Likewise Tacitus the Roman historian

The more corrupt the state, the more numerous the laws

Perhaps the best conspective summary is from the South American dictator who said:

For my friends anything; for my enemies the law


One of my favorite songs has this lyric: Everybody wants to rule the world. In human society three roles emerge: rule makers; rule breakers; and rule takers. Another way to understand the evolution of law is that people create social conflict whenever we interact with each other. The philosophical concepts of elected officials and the rule of law is just an imperfect effort to resolve such conflicts via the democratic election of officials in the legislatures and judicial branch of public institutions. In theory official rule makers should be rule takers. Who interprets the law in a dispute?

@SystemTheory what do you mean "takers"?

Rule takers are people who do not break the rules. Governments throughout history were populated by people who wanted to be rule makers but not rule takers. The authoritarian rule makers want authority to make the rules, interpret the rules, and selectively enforce the rules against their enemies but not against their friends. Hypocrites like the concept of Master morality it appeals to their fantasy of ruling the world. I don't think Nietsche or any individual is necessarily a hypocrite until I observe their desire to enforce the rules on others and be exempt from the rules or above the law.
